# Modify CSS inside a Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, shadow-dom

I have a shadow DOM being created by a third party. I want to set the `display` of a div with class `.controls` inside the shadow DOM to `none`. How can I achieve this via CSS?

```
<div class="documentation__design">
  <figspec-file-viewer>
    #shadow-root (open)
      <div class="controls">
        <select></select>
      </div>
      <div class="view"></div>
  </figspec-file-viewer>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually haven't done this before but I looked around. Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_shadow_parts) can help?

Comment: Thanks @cub. This would do the trick but I cannot add the part attribute inside the shadow DOM since it is being rendered by the third-party.

Comment: See the code in the developers tool and see how they achieved the shadow, then in your CSS file modify it to your liking with ```!important``` value to ensure it will apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to directly reach into the shadowRoot, get the`.controls` element and set the inline style

```
document
   .querySelector("figspec-file-viewer")
   .shadowRoot
   .querySelector(".controls")
   .style
   .display = "none";
```

or **append** a `<style>` tag to the shadowRoot:

```
document
   .querySelector("figspec-file-viewer")
   .shadowRoot
   .append(
      Object.assign( document.createElement("STYLE") ,
                     {
                       innerHTML : `.controls {
                                       display : "none";
                                     }`
                     }
                    )// Object.assign
          )// append
```

As mentioned in the comments a `part` could do.
With the above mentioned method you can set a `part` **attribute** on any DOM element *inside* shadowDOM, and then use **global CSS(*)** to style it.

(*) Strictly speaking not global CSS but CSS in the *container* where the shadowRoot was created in. Thus with **3** levels of shadowRoot, set the `:part` CSS in the 2nd shadowRoot.

***or*** to pass nested part definitions to its parent container see the `exportparts` attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/exportparts

Ofcourse all this magic can only be done on **open** shadowRoots!

`super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})`